# how do you prevent functions inside useEffect from being triggered more than once?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

There is an ESLint rule `exhaustive-deps` which checks the dependency array of your Hooks (ex:`useEffect`).  My question lies around the impact of having the content of the useEffect be triggered more often due to things like functions now being tracked.
This can have a negative impact when an api call is inside an effect because you would only want the API to be called once.
I could break up the Effect more, and maybe it helps with the dep array...maybe not...

**How do you prevent content from being triggered more than its needed?**
For me, in order to prevent the extra calls to API service, I either need to ignore the lint rule (no!) or have more checks in place around my code, as well as have local state about the status:

Example to prevent the session & api call from being triggered more than once:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!saveValues) {  // is this an anti-pattern?
      return;
    }
    if (!sessionId && !wasSaving && savingForm) {
      initSession().then(() => { // 1st call to session service to get Id
        setSendRequest(true); // set local state that it's safe to send API request because I have my session ready
      });
    } else if (sendRequest && sessionId) {
      setSendRequest(false); // immediately set local state back to false so the previous block doesnt fire.
      try {
        const fields = userFields
          .filter(field => !isEmpty(saveValues[field.name]))
          .map(field => {
              name: field.name,
              value,
            };
          );
        insertUser({ sessionId, fields, config, newRoles }) // here's my API call now
          .then(() => saveSession(sessionId)) // 2nd call to session service req'd
      } catch (err) {
        const message = err.message.split('desc = ')[1];
        setSaveRequestError(message);
        setSavingForm(false);
        setSaveModalOpen(false);
        quitSession(sessionId);
      }
    }
    return () => {
      if (sessionId) {
        quitSession(sessionId);
      }
    };
  }, [
    initSession,
    insertUser,
    quitSession,
    roles.rolesList,
    saveSession,
    saveValues,
    savingForm,
    sendRequest,
    sessionId,
    userFields,
    wasSaving,
  ]);
```

as a side note, interestingly, the hooks for state, like setSaveRequestError, setSavingForm do not show up in dep array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to react documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#complex-components-become-hard-to-understand) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns) it is better to put  each of your conditions to a separate `useEffect` instead of a single complex one. Each `useEffect` has its own dependency array and do specific job.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to avoid executing it again (and you don't want to pass an empty dep array) useRef is your friend since it does not rerender the component (not a state):

```
let hasBeenExecuted = useRef(false);
//In effect
if(!hasBeenExecuted.current) {
    // Do stuff
    hasBeenExecuted.current = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for being late. This repository is to solve this problem.

[react-use-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-watch)

```
useWatch(() => {
  // your logic
}, [your dependency])
```

Solve this problem neatly and perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

useEffect gets called every time a dependency passed to it changes and runs the entire code inside it.

Note: useEffect(() => {}, [dependency1, dependency2 ...])

If you want your code inside the useEffect to be called only when the component loads initially, pass empty array as dependency.

Comment: correct about the dep array.  I am not trying to have this called only when the component loads, but later on, when `savingForm` is true.